# Recommendation for code hosting of personal projects

Tags: project-management, bazaar

I tired my hands on bazaar(launchpad), for the reason that i can host my project at launchpad, and bazaar (my local machine) would be tightly integrated with launchpad. I have posted my question at launchpad forum, and have not got any answer. Anyways...

So i was thinking about shifting it from there to some other site. I dont know why, but couple of friends said sourceforge has not remain that good, but i still see too many project linking to sourceforge.

PS recommendation. Is there a place where you guys upload your personal projects, and also SVN I think is the most popular, but with git/bazaar, I dont know if it just a hype or distributed version controlling is really the way to go.

Comment: If you have some server somewhere that you can use, I would check this thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007679/how-can-i-host-git-repositories-and-manage-my-content-hosting-myself). Affordable shell-servers are pretty cheap nowadays. Amazon AWS such as EC2 [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) could be an ideal solution for some of you, you pay what you use and repo -content-hosting does not require that much traffic (heard that it becomes actually cheaper than the traditional marketed-host -services after the front-up cost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have many personal projects at Google Code. It's easy to use, and lets other people find and use my code.

For minor personal projects (mostly projects I show off on my web site), I actually use [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/). It's got what I need for my own needs:

1. I can work on my code on several machines (it syncs files across machines.)
2. I can access my files through the web (it has a web interface.)
3. If I need to go back to an old version of a file, or restore a deleted file, I can do that through the web interface (it stores a revision every time the file is modified, and it's easy to see a list of versions and download them or choose to replace the current version.)

It's also got support for making part of the structure public, so that others can download the latest version of the code. You can even share the folder so that others with Dropbox can modify the files.

[Check it out!](http://www.getdropbox.com/)

Comment: as a mattar of fact, i just installed dropbox y'day after rejecting ubuntu-one, which according to me is still buggy. But i need one to learn how to SCM works.

Comment: Comment on use of dropbox. I use dropbox for sharing files, but for my projects and my documents, i use syncplicity. I find it faster, it has bigger free space, and also keeps versions longer than dropbox now does. dropbox limits to 30 days now i believe, while syncplicity, well it has versions as far back as 6 months! :)

Comment: +1 for dropbox. It's very simple!   
syncplicity FREE has no more space than dropbox. `Start with 2GB storage and sync to 2 devices for FREE.`

Comment: -1 for Dropbox, it may be "Free as Beer" but is not "FREE as speech", you cannot break it or make it better -- it is GUI hack. Check out Gitolite and some affordable -shell-hosting -- then you can also have friends(perms)' management :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm very happy with [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) for my personal stuff. They offer all kinds of version control and project management tools (SVN, Git, Trac, etc). It's free for public projects (though there is a storage limit for these) and they offer rather affordable private plans (which I like a lot for managing my personal stuff with tickets, wiki etc).

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's 2 problems here.  1) What to use for SCM, and 2) Where to host your project.  I'd settle on a SCM system first, then choose a host that you like which supports your provided system.  As for personal preference, I like SVN, and have been hosting projects at google code lately.  Google code is kind of new, and not super feature-rich, but isn't too bad as far as hosts go.

Comment: Thanks Ryan i will wait for other answers too, i am using VCS (or SCM, i donot know if they are the same), and ofcourse as everyone might guess i dont need feature, mainly just to backup my project on the web, and get use to VCSs.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial (and Git I believe) has a built-in web interface that easily links to your repository and allows you to host the code yourself. It provides a customizable web interface for code browsing, and allows other to clone a repo from your site instead of from SFEE. Additionally, you can set up password protection to allow a certain set of users to check into each repository.

Check out [this link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) to see how to host repositories using Apache, and [this link](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/) for Mercurial info in general.

Answer (score 2):

http://bzr.bz (my project) does private bzr + trac hosting

- its not free but its cheap
- perfect for personal projects etc.. that are not open source

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe nobody as mentioned [Github](http://github.com/) yet!  Github offers free git hosting for open source projects, and paid hosting otherwise.

[Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) offers free SVN hosting, but with a Diskspace limit of 100MB and only 3 users.  You can pay to have it upgraded.

Both of these are good choices (Depending on whether or not you like Git/SVN of course), and are obviously globally accessible via the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late answer by now, but personally I recommend http://repositoryhosting.com/

They offer SVN/GIT/HG hosting with Trac support, WebDAV, unlimited projects/unlimited users for 6$ a month.

I've tried other providers (assembla, github and even tried to put it on my own server), but this deal beats all competitors. I was even able to put it on my own subdomain.

Their interface is a bit minimalistic, but it does the job very well.